# I need to change tabs names in tabhost

Tags: android

I am a beginner and I need to know how to change Tab names and Fragment names in my app please help me , and when i use a string and provide names for tabs and change the logic to tab Names.length then my app crashes saying "unfortunately app has been stopped". please help me fixing this.

Here is the main activity.java code

```
package com.tech2dsk.musicdsk;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.tech2dsk.adapters.MyFragmentPagerAdapter;
import com.tech2dsk.fragments.Fragment1;
import com.tech2dsk.fragments.Fragment2;
import com.tech2dsk.fragments.Fragment3;
import com.tech2dsk.fragments.Fragment4;
import com.tech2dsk.musicdsk.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener {

    private TabHost tabHost;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyFragmentPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    int i = 0;

    // fake content for tabhost
    class FakeContent implements TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public FakeContent(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        i++;

        // init tabhost
        this.initializeTabHost(savedInstanceState);

        // init ViewPager
        this.initializeViewPager();

    }

    private void initializeViewPager() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

        fragments.add(new Fragment1());
        fragments.add(new Fragment2());
        fragments.add(new Fragment3());
        fragments.add(new Fragment4());


        this.myViewPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        this.viewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        this.viewPager.setAdapter(this.myViewPagerAdapter);
        this.viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

        onRestart();

    }

    private void initializeTabHost(Bundle args) {

        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

            TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
            tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab " + i);
            tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab " + i);
            tabSpec.setContent(new FakeContent(this));
            tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        }
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int pos = this.tabHost.getCurrentTab();
        this.viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

        HorizontalScrollView hScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hScrollView);
        View tabView = tabHost.getCurrentTabView();
        int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft()
                - (hScrollView.getWidth() - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;
        hScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollPos, 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        this.tabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know you are using deprecated methods? You should use AppCompatActivity, Toolbar and ViewPager instead.

Comment: yeah will change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in your xml inside <TabWidget>

```
             <TextView
                android:tag="tab0"
                android:text="Tab 1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
            <TextView
                android:tag="tab1"
                android:text="Tab 2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
            <TextView
                android:tag="tab2"
                android:text="Tab 3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
```

Comment: i have  included my logic in mainactivity.java itself , so making changes to activity_main.xml deoesnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, add this method to your FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return translateIntoName(position); //replace this with your logic
}
```

Also instead of tabhost, you should use [TabLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout).